# About Jamaa SMPP Asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, smpp

I have successfully implemented an application using Jamaa Lib and Jamaa Net. Thanks to the developers.

But I am facing a problem when I use Asynchronous sending operation. An unhandled exception is being raised continuously. Would be highly appreciated if someone can help me to figure out the problem.

Please be noted. I am receiving and sending SMS using the same application. I need to send on an average 100,000 SMS per day. Simultaneously I am receiving SMS from SMSC also. Thanks in advance.

My Code snippet

```
namespace Transciever 
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmppClient client = new SmppClient();
        MySQLConnect con = new MySQLConnect();
        TextMessage msg = new TextMessage();
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        SmppConnectionProperties properties = client.Properties;
        string sysid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SystemID"];
        string pswd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        string hst = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
        int port = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
        properties.SystemID = sysid;
        properties.Password = pswd;
        properties.Port = port ; //IP port to use
        properties.Host = hst; //SMSC host name or IP Address
        properties.SystemType = "";
        properties.DefaultServiceType = "";
        //Resume a lost connection after 30 seconds
        client.AutoReconnectDelay = 3000;
        //SmppClient client1=GetSmppClient();
        //Send Enquire Link PDU every 15 seconds
        client.KeepAliveInterval = 15000;

        //Start smpp client
        try
        {
            client.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
        client.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>(client_MessageReceived);
        while (true)
        {
            client.ConnectionStateChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {

                switch (e.CurrentState)
                {

                    case SmppConnectionState.Closed:
                        // Connection to the remove server is lost

                        try
                        {
                            client.Start();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                        break;

                    case SmppConnectionState.Connected:
                        //Console.Write("Connected");
                        break;

                    case SmppConnectionState.Connecting:
                        break;

                }

            };


            String successQuery = "";
            var list = new List<smsoutbox>();
            list = con.Select("select msgID, srcMN,dstMN, msg from table where msgStatus='QUE' order by msgID desc LIMIT 500");
            int listcount = list.Count;
            int i = 0;
            if (listcount > 0 && client.ConnectionState == SmppConnectionState.Connected)
            {
                foreach (var row in list)
                {
                    i = i + 1;
                    msg.DestinationAddress = row.dstMN;
                    msg.Text = row.msg;
                    msg.SourceAddress = row.srcMN;
                    msg.RegisterDeliveryNotification = false;
                    successQuery += row.msgID.ToString() + ",";
                    try
                    {
                        client.BeginSendMessage(msg, SendMessageCompleteCallback, client);                        

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {


                    }
                    if (i == 250)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (successQuery.Length > 0)
                            {
                                successQuery = successQuery.Substring(0, successQuery.Length - 1);
                                successQuery = "update smsoutbox_bl set msgStatus='SENT' where msgID in (" + successQuery + ")";
                                con.Update(successQuery);
                                successQuery = "";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                        i = 0;
                    }//if i==250 ends

                }//foreach ends
            }//if listcount>0 ends

            if (i > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (successQuery.Length > 0)
                    {
                        successQuery = successQuery.Substring(0, successQuery.Length - 1);

                        successQuery = "update smsoutbox_bl set msgStatus='SENT' where msgID in (" + successQuery + ")";
                        //dbConnection.RunSql(successQuery);
                        con.Update(successQuery);
                        successQuery = "";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }//while loop ends
    }//main ends

    static public void client_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        //The event argument e contains more information about the received message
        TextMessage textMsg = e.ShortMessage as TextMessage; //This is the received text message
        try
        {
            MyWebRequest myRequest = new MyWebRequest("http://localhost/cde/cdeblrecv.php", "POST", "mn=" + textMsg.SourceAddress + "&msg=" + textMsg.Text + "&sc=3333");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    static private void SendMessageCompleteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        SmppClient client = (SmppClient)result.AsyncState;
        client.EndSendMessage(result);
    }


}//class program ends here
}//namespace ends here
```

---

Below is the exception thrown by the app.

> Unhandled Exception: JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.SmppException: Exception
>   of type 'JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.SmppException' was thrown.

Server stack trace:

> at JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Client.SmppClient.SendMessage(ShortMessage
>   message, Int32 timeOut)  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)  at
>   JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Client.SendMessageCallBack.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)  at
>   JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Client.SmppClient.EndSendMessage(IAsyncResult
>   result)  at
>   Transciever.Program.SendMessageCompleteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
>   in
>   d:\smpp\transciever\appTranscieverinCSharp\appTranscieverinCSharp\Program.cs:line
>   223  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object
>   o)  at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use wireshark to view the raw packets, this will give you an idea what is going wrong. In my case it was an invalid system id.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your credentials and also need to add following statements:

```
client.Properties.InterfaceVersion = InterfaceVersion.v34;
client.Properties.DefaultEncoding = DataCoding.SMSCDefault;
client.Properties.SourceAddress = "XXXXX";
client.Properties.AddressNpi = NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
client.Properties.AddressTon = TypeOfNumber.Unknown;
client.Properties.SystemType = "XXXX";
client.Properties.DefaultServiceType = ServiceType.DEFAULT;
```

It will help you and will definitely remove this exception.
Please mark it if you find this answer useful.